# How do I catch this EntityNotFound exception in AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

When i make this call (trying to fetch a table from AWS Glue that doesn't exist):
`glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database='wrong_database_name', table_name='or_wrong_table_name')`

I get an exception like this

> An error occurred while calling o79.getCatalogSource.
> : com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.EntityNotFoundException: Entity Not Found (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: EntityNotFoundException; Request ID: 4f26a2ed-c7cc-48d4-bfe3-101816abe56d; Proxy: null

How do I go about catching this exception?
I tried both of these and neither work:

```
import botocore

try:
    glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database='wrong_database_name',
    table_name='or_wrong_table_name')
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as err:
    if err.response['Error']['Code'] == 'EntityNotFoundException':
        # ...


import boto3
glue = boto3.client('glue')
try:
    glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database='wrong_database_name',
    table_name='or_wrong_table_name')
except glue.exceptions.EntityNotFoundException:
       # ...
```

the second one asks two arguments towards the __ init __ method of the exception so that seems strange / not the way to go about things ..
Anybody else come across this?

Answer (score 0):

It's included in boto3. Simply do:

```
import boto3

raise EntityNotFoundException
```